# Is there a mistake in the flags shown at the World's Fair?

Tags: production-mistakes, loki

In Season 2, Episode 3, Loki travels to 1893. At a fair in Chicago, the Russian flag is visible. But the Russian flag appeared later AFAIK. Some other flags are wrong too.

[image]

Was this a mistake?

Comment: I haven't watched Season 2 yet, but based on how Season 1 ended, it seems possible to me that this is an alternate timeline that doesn't quite match up with our own reality.

Comment: All alternate timelines are killed. (I do not call it reality, only one timeline can exists and we can not travel backwards in RL). You think about a time-travel backward to split a new timeline? Maybe, but the mess is perfect since end of Season 1.

Comment: Not so. There is an explicit statement that this is a BRANCHED timeline.

Comment: There's no shortage of countries with those colours on their flag; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_flags_with_blue,_red,_and_white_stripes;  Russia, Slovakia, Transnistria, First Slovak Republic, etc that existed at the time of the World's Fair

Comment: @Tetsujin 1. Denmark, 2. India, 3. Korea, 4. Mexico, 5. Thailand, 6. China, 7. Portugal,  8. Iran/Persia, 9. Scotland, 10. El Salvador, 11. Brazil, 12. Australia, 13. Switzerland, 14. Russia, 15. Spain, 16. Uruguay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [between 1883 and 1896, the black-yellow-white State Flag of the Russian Empire was being gradually replaced with the white-blue-red flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Russian_flags#Civil_ensign_and_national_flag), so this usage seems correct.

> On 28 April 1883, Alexander III amended the 1858 decree "on flags for decorating buildings on solemn occasions" to be replaced exclusively with the white-blue-red colours. This meant that the white-blue-red flag was now to be used on land in addition to at seas.

Answer (score 6):

> 1893. At a fair in Chicago, the Russian flag is visible. But the Russian flag appeared later AFAIK.

The first [Russian flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Russia) appears in 1696 until 1917/1923, then again in 1991/93. The CIS/SFSR kept the same colours. It seems to be the good flag here.

> The Russian tricolour flag was adopted as a merchant flag at rivers in 1705. These colours of the flag of Russia would later inspire the choice of the "Pan-Slavic colours" by the Prague Slavic Congress, 1848. Two other Slavic countries, Slovakia and Slovenia, have flags similar to the Russian one, but with added coats-of-arms for differentiation. On 7 May 1883, the Russian flag was authorized to be used on land, and it became an official National flag before the coronation of Tsar Nicholas II in 1896.

From left to right (visible ones only), at the time of the episode (1893): ? - [Canada](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Canada_(1868%E2%80%931921).svg) - [Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korea) - [Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico) - [Thailand / Siam](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Siam_(1855).svg) - [China](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_China_(1889%E2%80%931912).svg) - [Portugal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Portugal) - [Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Iran) - [Scotland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotland) - [El Salvador](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_El_Salvador#Historical_flags_of_El_Salvador) - [Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil) - [Australian Federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Federation_Flag)(?) - [Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switzerland) - Russia - [Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain) - [Uruguay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switzerland)

These flags seem to be historically OK (if I correctly identified them & with help of comment by [@jkej](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/121271/is-there-a-mistake-in-the-flags-shown-at-the-worlds-fair#comment214685_121271) and [@AlanBirtles](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/121271/is-there-a-mistake-in-the-flags-shown-at-the-worlds-fair#comment214717_121271)).

Comment: The wiki-article said: black on the top, gold in the middle, and white on the bottom (1858-1896)

Comment: The rightmost one looks like [Uruguay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Uruguay) to me.

Comment: @Grim "On 7 May 1883, the [white, blue, and red] Russian flag was authorized to be used on land, and it became an official National flag before the coronation of Tsar Nicholas II in 1896." Both it and the black, yellow, white flag were in use in 1893.

Comment: The flag with the elephant to the right of the Mexican flag appears to be the [flag of Thailand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Thailand) in 1893.

Comment: 1. Denmark, 2. India, 3. Korea, 4. Mexico, 5. Thailand, 6. China, 7. Portugal,  8. Iran/Persia, 9. Scotland, 10. El Salvador, 11. Brazil, 12. Australia, 13. Switzerland, 14. Russia, 15. Spain, 16. Uruguay

Comment: 1 could also be Savoy, Malta, Order of St. John etc., but Denmark seems most likely in this context .Yellow blob could be Danish coat of arms, although I haven't seen an example where it's placed like that.

Comment: @jkej 2 looks more like [canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Ensign) than India

Comment: @AlanBirtles: I searched all the flags from the British empire and the Commonwealth but there's that little part (bottom right of the flag) that isn't on any of the ones I found

Comment: @OldPadawan looking at the original video it's probably [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Canada_(1868%E2%80%931921).svg), though (at least for me) the disney plus video quality isn't great so it's difficult to tell. The one on the left behind the roof looks like Ireland

Comment: @AlanBirtles I couldn't find a Canadian version with that much yellow, so I thought it was [this Indian flag](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:British_Raj_Red_Ensign.svg). But the one you found may be an even better fit, especially if you have access to the original video.

Comment: @OldPadawan Here are links to the flags of [Thailand/Siam](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Siam_(1855).svg) and [China](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_China_(1889%E2%80%931912).svg) that I think are in the picture in case you want to add them to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As can be see in the [World Flag Chart 1893](https://flaglog.com/1893), the left-most flag is Samoa. I initially thought Denmark or Savoy, but Savoy wasn't independent by 1893 and no Danish flag I can find has any star or coat of arms in the top left. Samoa has the upper-left star in that date.

Comment: Good catch! To make it easier to check: [Kingdom of Samoa](https://www.fotw.info/flags/ws_king.html)

Comment: Sorry, I will not take effort to decide if you are more right than the others. You may be more right but I decided to have an raw range of accepting the most correct answer. Even though, nice link.